# regex - match character which is not escaped

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to match unescaped comma characters in a string.

The rule I'm looking for is "A comma not preceded by an even number of backslashes".

Test cases:

```
True    abc,abc
False   abc\,abc
True    abc\\,abc
False   abc\\\,abc
True    abc\\\\,abc
False   abc\\\\\,abc
```

I tried to use a negative look-behind: `(?<!(\\+)),` but Python gives me `error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.

Comment: try using raw strings `r'...'` to declare the regex

Comment: Why is the first example true? It's not escaped. Can't you just count the number of slashes and determine whether that's even?

Comment: @JBernardo I'm using raw strings already. I'm looking for characters that are not escaped, updated title to clarify.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this regex: `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*,`

Explanation:

```
(?<!\\)    Matches if the preceding character is not a backslash
(?:\\\\)*  Matches any number of occurrences of two backslashes
,          Matches a comma
```

Comment: One slight issue though is that the match group contains all preceding backslashes. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Why is that a problem? You already know that the last character of the match is the comma.

Comment: I understated the problem, and would need to find the offset of the comma. Can be worked around with a little arithmetic anyways!

Comment: The comma will be at `m.end() - 1`, where `m` is the match object returned by the search.

Comment: Surround the command with parentheses: `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(,)`. Now the comma will be in the capture group.